# How to setup multiple subdomains on lampp?

Tags: linux, subdomain, apache-2.2, cakephp

down vote  favorite

Hi ,

I need to set up multiple projects on lampp. How can i create sub domains for these multiple projects.

My projects are in cakePHP.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

[root@rajat Rajat]# vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
#    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
#</VirtualHost>
```

change according to your requirement

Answer (score 2):

[DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/)

Answer (score 1):

The official Apache documentation has an excellent chapter about [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) with real-world examples. Read that first and then ask if there's something you don't understand. :)